# Stop blurred header image from being slightly see-through

Tags: css

I'm working on a header that shrinks down to 40px + blurs the background-image when you scroll which works fine, however when i do scroll, because of the blur, you can kind of see content peaking through the blurred header as you go down the page. I'm still learning all of the css transitions and filters, so I was wondering if there's a way to prevent this?

My code for it is

```
.blur-header{
   height:40px;
   -webkit-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
   -moz-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
   -o-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
   -ms-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

and I created an example to show exactly what's going on with the opacity of the blurred image:

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('header').addClass('blur-header');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('blur-header');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-image: url("http://www.theyucatantimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/pet.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
}

.blur-header {
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -o-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-content {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

img {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER TEXT</header>

<div class="main-content">
  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: what would you expect it to look like?

Comment: In your case you are adding blur to the heading which will applied for the inner content of header. In order to make it happen you need to have separate section for blur. Don't mix it with the header

Comment: obviously that's how it should be rendered. Tell us what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lessen the amount of blur from 10px to around 3-5px;

```
.blur-header{
   height:40px;
   -webkit-filter: blur(3px) brightness(1);
   -moz-filter: blur(3px) brightness(1);
   -o-filter: blur(3px) brightness(1);
   -ms-filter: blur(3px) brightness(1);
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

It starts blurring from the edge in, so the large amount of pixels, the more are being taken off the height/width of your image. If you would like to blur more and keep the original sizing, I would suggest creating a separate `<div>` that holds the header that you can apply the blur to.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is your solved problem. I added a extra `div` near the header which will blur on scroll and added `z-index` to your header in order to keep it in the top layer.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.blur').addClass('blur-header');
  } else {
    $('.blur').removeClass('blur-header');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 99;
}

.blur {
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url("http://www.theyucatantimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/pet.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.blur-header {
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -o-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px) brightness(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-content {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

img {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>HEADER TEXT</header>
<div class="blur">
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">

  <img src="https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/newfoundland-dogs-and-puppies/newfoundland-dogs-puppies-1.jpg">
</div>
```